# how to use split() function with html tag and whitespace

Tags: javascript, html, string, split, whitespace

I use `split(" ")` for whitespace and use `split(/(<[^>]*>)/)` for html tag in string.

but i have to use together. i want to divide a string by whitespace and html tag and put it into an array. i don't want to lose anything. string, html tag both.

whitespace is `\s` and html tag is `split(/(<[^>]*>)/)` and i used like this `new RegExp("\s+(<[^>]*>)", "g");`

but it doesn't work.

```
var htmlTagRegex = new RegExp("\s+(<[^>]*>)", "g");     

    var str = ""<div class="tab0">CSS code formatter</div><div class="tab2">CSS code compressor</div>";
    var myArray = str.split(htmlTagRegex);

    if(myArray != null){
        for ( i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++ ) { 
            var result = "myArray[" + i + "] = " + myArray[i]+"<br />";
            $(".tt-sns-clear").append(result);
        }           
    }
```

Comment: [Don't try to parse HTML with regex; use an XML parser.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not 100% sure what you are trying to do but it looks like the space needs to be optional like `\s*` instead of `\s+`

Something like : `\s*(<[^>]*>)`

And since you are not  concatenating a string to your Regex better is:

```
var htmlTagRegex =/\s*(<[^>]*>)/g
```

The input string is not using double quotes correctly and it is not compiling either, you need to mix single and double quotes:

```
 '<div class="tab0">CSS code formatter</div><div class="tab2">CSS code compressor</div>';
```

All together looks like

```
    var htmlTagRegex =/\s*(<[^>]*>)/g     

    var str = '<div class="tab0">CSS code formatter</div><div class="tab2">CSS code compressor</div>';
    var myArray = str.split(htmlTagRegex);

//outputs ["", "<div class="tab0">", "CSS code formatter", "</div>", "", "<div class="tab2">", "CSS code compressor", "</div>", ""]
```

And it seems to work fine on my end.

Answer (score 0):

string is from mysql. And that is inclueded html tag.

And I used like this: var htmlTagRegex =/\s|(<[^>]*>)/g;

but result is not what i want.

```
["","CSS","code","formatter","<div class="tab0"></div>","","CSS","code","compressor","<div class="tab1"></div>"]
```

I want like this

```
["<div class="tab0">","CSS","code","formatter","","<div class="tab1">","CSS","code","compressor","</div>"]
```